# How can I display multiple longitude/latitude on google maps using Angular 4

Tags: angular, google-maps

I want to display multiple locations on a google map at the same time using json.

I am not sure how to do that. I have displayed a map but with only one position

Here is the json:

```
{
    "post_country": "Vietnam",
    "post_latitude": 10.4452129,
    "post_longitude": 106.4729811
},

{
    "post_country": "Kyrgyzstan",
    "post_latitude": 41.1694718,
    "post_longitude": 75.8098141
},

{
    "post_country": "China",
    "post_latitude": 34.2456501,
    "post_longitude": 108.9877602
},
```

I have used some values randomly in the below example

**Here is my code:**

```
<agm-map [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude" >

</agm-map>

latitude: number = 51.678418;
longitude: number = 7.809007;
```

Comment: <agm-map [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude" >

</agm-map>

Comment: in the google maps library there is markers, add marker, remove marker, and so on, check the docs of the library you are using for this thing

Answer (score 2):

You can try this, works for me:

> HTML:

```
<agm-map  [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" >        
    <agm-marker  *ngFor = "let post of positions" [latitude]="post.post_latitude" [longitude]="post.post_longitude"></agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

> .ts:

```
lat = 6.05246325;
log = 9.01555559;

positions = [{
    "post_country": "Vietnam",
    "post_latitude": 10.4452129,
    "post_longitude": 106.4729811
}, {
    "post_country": "Kyrgyzstan",
    "post_latitude": 41.1694718,
    "post_longitude": 75.8098141
}, {
    "post_country": "China",
    "post_latitude": 34.2456501,
    "post_longitude": 108.9877602
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add some `<agm-marker></agm-marker>` into the `<agm-map></agm-map>`, according to the [official documentation](https://angular-maps.com/guides/getting-started/).

```
<agm-map [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude">
   <agm-marker [latitude]="lat1" [longitude]="long1"></agm-marker>
   <agm-marker [latitude]="lat2" [longitude]="long2"></agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

Just replace the latitude et longitude attributes by values from your json.

See this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-google-maps-demo?file=app%2Fapp.component.html).